# First isomorphism theorem. How is this proof sufficient

Tags: ring-theory

[image]

I don't understand it. See for it to be isomorphism you need to it to be homomorphism between them. I can see how this is trivial from what's worked out. I can sort of agree that surjection condition is obvious. However, don't see how he proves injection.

If $af=bf$, then I see that $a-b \in Kerf$. However, I don't see how this gives the injection condition. Looking at the proofwiki doesn't help as it uses a totally different proof. Plus can't get algebra 2 notes that I used last year.

Comment: If $a - b$ is in the kernel, then $[a] = [b]$. This establishes well-definition and injectivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a-b\in \ker f$ then $a,b$ define the same cosets, which means you started with the same elements, which is what injectivity tells you should happen!

Comment: Oh, I feel sort of stupid now. Thanks.

Comment: You gotta feel stupid at least once in a while, right? Don't worry about that. =) We all do anyway.